Missing an options in a function does not work as expected
i define the function f
ClearAll[f,g]
Options[f]={p->1,q->2};
f[a_:10,b_:20,OptionsPattern[]]:=
Module[
{paux=OptionValue[p],qaux=OptionValue[q]},
g[a,b,paux,qaux]
]

with f[15,q->4] i get g[15,q->4,1,2] but i expect g[15, 20, 1, 4]
what's wrong?
